# NSBundle returning every system framework

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks, nsbundle

On Mountain Lion, using Xcode 4.6.2, the following code

```
for (NSBundle *aBundle in [NSBundle allFrameworks]) NSLog(@"%@", [aBundle bundlePath]);
```

logs EVERYTHING, I mean every framework installed in the system (so not just the app's ones, as stated in NSBundle documentation).

Can this be normal?

Comment: It may just be that it's including the `usr/lib` frameworks that get implicitly linked against by the runtime and other libraries.  Are you sure it's *every* system framework?

Comment: You are absolutely right.

Comment: I'll put that up as an answer, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libraries that are implicitly linked to, either by the runtime or by the frameworks you link to themselves, are also included in that list.  It may not be *every* system framework, but it certainly is quite a lot.